# Custom subnet for Digital Ocean private networks

Tags: networking, linux-networking, digital-ocean

Hopefully this is a quick fix that someone can help me out with. I have spun up some droplets & enabled private networking. They communicate with each other with no issues.
The current subnet let's say is:

```
10.12.0.0/24
```

I would love some help with creating a custom subnet for droplets to communicate over on the private network at say:

```
10.14.0.0/24
```

If both subnets could be kept in place that would be great.

I have tried adding additional IP addresses to the lan interfaces (in this case, `eth1` since the droplets are running Ubuntu) on my droplets and routing appear correct when I check `route -n` (custom subnet has the settings that mimic the default private subnet exactly); iptables rules are also present to pass/accept traffic from the custom subnet but I get no joy when trying to ping between droplets.

I hope what I'm trying to do is clear enough but I'll gladly supply more detail if it is needed. I just thought I should check if there is a limitation of sorts with the DO infrastructure in case I'm wasting time doing something that isn't possible.

Comment: Don't use other people's public IP address ranges. Use RFC1918 ranges instead.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton I've updated the question; I am using RFC1918 ranges. I didn't think through my example well enough when I was writing the question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please provide the real subnet size? /32 is impossible (because it's not network but a single IP not being able to communicate). If you get provided a /24 subnet for example you can subdivide it but to have a different net you would need to contact your provider. E. g. if You have a 10.10.10.0/24 net you could subdivide it into 10.10.10.0/27 - 10.10.10.224/27, each net containing 30 Host IPs +1 net IP + 1 Broadcast IP = 32 IPs per subnet, a total 8 subnets. Or if you use /25 you can subdivide into 2 nets with 126 hosts each.

Comment: I've updated the question with real subnet size. However I have had feedback from digital ocean which I will use to answer the question.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a VPN? If security isn't an issue you could also make do with IP in IP tunnels [ip-tunnel(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-tunnel.8.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received feedback from digital ocean regarding this & at present time one is unable to use custom subnets & IPs to communicate over the private LAN on DO infrastructure. I believe that if they did support it then adding additional IPs and appropriate routing table info would just work.

Feedback from my support request to digital ocean is quoted below.

> Sorry for any inconvenience it may cause but at this time there is not any way to acquire a different or an additional private IP address for a Droplet. If this is a feature you would like to see added we recommend sharing it on our ideas page which is available at https://ideas.digitalocean.com . This way we can gather input from the community and get a better insight into what users are requesting.

This may obviously change in the future. I have resolved to experiment with OpenVPN to try achieve my desired setup.